# JavaFX и зависимости программ

Tags: java, javafx, graph

Необходимо в Windows получить данные про зависимость программ на компьютере(дан пример пути к ним на linux(/var/lib/dpkg/avalible)).
После получения данных, необходимо создать граф на котором можно двигать точки. Подскажите как получить эти данные и есть ли библиотека для визуализации графов на Java, или же писать это все ручками?

Comment: Нашел отличную библиотеку для визуализации графов
[ссылка](http://graphstream-project.org/)
Но откуда получать данные так и не понял, прошу, помогите